# Get an iframe source code from remote site based on Id

Tags: php, domdocument, simple-html-dom

I want to get the source code of iframe from remote site, then echo it to my site. i think the best way is through php either through php Dom or library like simple_html_dom_parser.

here is my try:

```
<?php
  include_once('simple_html_dom.php');
  $url = ('http://remotesite);          
  $html = file_get_html($url);                                 
  $content = $html->find('iframe#target',0);
  echo $content;
?>
```

but this get me this

```
<iframe allowtransparency="true" id="target"  scrolling="no" width="650">  </iframe>
```

however the iframe in the remote site is like this:

```
<iframe allowTransparency="true" id="target" scrolling="no" width="650" allowtransparency="no" frameborder="0" src="domain.com/page.html" height="500"> </iframe>
```

what is wrong with my method?

Comment: here is the full html code of the remote site containing the iframe i want to get (id=player) http://pastebin.com/TkP4Xd42

Comment: Probably, your remote url have JavaScript code that update the src for iframe.

Comment: @IgnacioOcampo in this case what can we do?

Comment: You could check if remote code have the frame id in some place within HTML code to get it, if not, you can use more advanced approach to get HTML code after rendered (http://phantomjs.org/).

Comment: @IgnacioOcampo yes the id i present within the source of remote age but when i get it, only get this <iframe allowtransparency="true" id="target"  scrolling="no" width="650">  </iframe> not the full iframe code check the questing deatils.

Comment: Probably, you see the full URL because your browser run and render html and scripts, and I think that the SRC attrib for the IFRAME are assigned dynamically. You could get the source in linux with: `wget http://server/page.html` to chech the real return html for your **file_get_html** function

Comment: Please let me know your email or skype id

Comment: Also giving the real url can help a lot telling if the source code is altered using JS, and maybe even suggest a workarround...

Comment: @Enissay here is an example url http://feed2all.eu/watch/193916/1/watch-skysports.html

Comment: Using cURL doesnt change anything... So probably the dom breaks after the duplicated `allowtransparency` attribute...

Comment: @Enissay can we use php dom and load the whole source code to $dom then get the iframe using getelementbyid? here is my try http://pastebin.com/E7jURgCz but i get blank page

Comment: What you get is normal since the `iframe` is empty... Try `echo $iframe->getAttribute("src");` instead :)

Comment: @Enissay yes this echo the source of the iframe correctly but now how manage to echo it?

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
echo htmlentities($iframe->ownerDocument->saveXML($iframe));
```